# How to using if for just a number, when the minus sign (-) just one in the front of the number that input from a user

Tags: python

So, I am tried to make a program that users just can input a number, but for the minus number, the minus sign (-) just one in front of the number. When the users input the wrong input, it will retry just until 5 times.

So, I just want the user input number like this

-1

-12

-123

Not like this

--1

--12

1-

1--

12-

12--

-1-

-12-

1-1

-1-1

and some tricks like that

The explanation for if statements:

`len(nama) > 0`

1. This is to avoid if the user inputs a blank input or just press Enter.

`re.match("^[-0-9]*$", nama)`

2. This is to make the users just input a number (0-9) and a minus sign (-).

`nama[1:] != "-"`

3. This is to make the user just can input the minus sign (-) in front of the number.

`nama[1:-1] != "-"`

4. This is to avoid the user input minus sign (-) after the first minus sign until the lattes.

`all([len(nama) > 0, re.match("^[-0-9]*$", nama), nama[1:] != "-", nama[1:-1] != "-"])`

5. This for if all statements right it will go to next. But I didn't sure using AND or OR for this or the code not look so good.

I tried that, but why after I input more than one minus sign (-) in front of the number and in the back, still print "Benar". That not what I want.

This is my first simple code:

````
for retry_nama in range(5):
    nama = input("masukkan nama: ")
    if all([len(nama) > 0, re.match("^[-0-9]*$", nama), nama[1:] != "-", nama[1:-1] != "-"]):
        print("Benar")
        input("press ENTER to exit")
        break
    print("salah, try again.")
else:
    print("You keep making invalid name, exiting now.")
    sys.exit(1)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not need for regular expressions for such a simple check:

```
def is_int(s):
    s = str(s)
    if s[0] in ('-', '+'):
        return s[1:].isdigit()
    return s.isdigit() 

for retry_nama in range(5):
    nama = input("masukkan nama: ")
    if is_int(nama):
        print("Benar")
        input("press ENTER to exit")
        break
    print("salah, try again.")
else:
    print("You keep making invalid name, exiting now.")
```

Comment: Wew wonderfull, this can solve my problem. I am still learning a basic of python yesterday  and still know just a little. So it can using function than using re. Thanks

Comment: but there is a bug, when I input with empty input, there is an error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\....", line 10, in <module>
    if is_int(nama):
  File "D:\....", line 3, in is_int
    if s[0] in ('-', '+'):
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: it is easily fixable in `is_int`, I'm sure you can figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to cast the number to `int` and see what happens:

```
sample_input = [
    "-1",
    "-12",
    "-123",
    "--1",
    "--12",
    "1-",
    "1--",
    "12-",
    "12--",
    "-1-",
    "-12-",
    "1-1",
    "-1-1",
]

for inp in sample_input:
    try:
        number = int(inp)
        print(f"Input is a valid int: {number}")
    except ValueError:
        print(f"{inp} is not a valid int.")
```

Which prints:

```
Input is a valid int: -1
Input is a valid int: -12
Input is a valid int: -123
--1 is not a valid int.
--12 is not a valid int.
1- is not a valid int.
1-- is not a valid int.
12- is not a valid int.
12-- is not a valid int.
-1- is not a valid int.
-12- is not a valid int.
1-1 is not a valid int.
-1-1 is not a valid int.
```

Which solves your examples.

Cheers!

Comment: It can be without using a sample?

Comment: What do you mean? If you mean an empty string: `int('')` it raises the same exception.

Comment: I mean, It can be without using sample_input? so its automatically, not I still fill the sample first

Comment: Sure, my code tests all the elements in `sample_input` just to be sure that every possibility you asked was covered, but the only relevant part is inside the `try except` block: those 5 lines are what you need.